# spring boot logging using log4j to external file with shared, external log4j configuration

Tags: spring, logging, spring-boot, log4j, yaml

i have a spring boot application. it pulls log4j.properties from an external location in my file system; i specify this file's location in my application.yml file:

```
...
logging:
  config: ${LOG_CONFIG_LOCATION}/log4j.properties
...
```

since the log4j.properties file will be shared by other applications, in it, i cannot use

```
...
log4j.appender.fileAppender.File=log_file_name.log
...
```

because ... all the applications would log to the same file (probably wouldn't work b/c of io)

what i want to do, is leverage the application's name specified in the application.yml file:

```
...
spring:
  application:
    name: my_foo_application
...
```

and set its log file name and location to

```
${LOG_FILES_LOCATION}/services/${spring.application.name}/${spring.application.name}.log
```

i tried this inside the application.yml file:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my_foo_application

logging:
  config: ${LOG_CONFIG_LOCATION}/log4j.properties
  file: ${LOG_FILES_LOCATION}/services/${spring.application.name}/${spring.application.name}.log
```

this had no effect - i do not see the log file in the location i'm expecting.

i also commented out the 'logging.file....' in application.yml & added this to the log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.appender.fileAppender.File=${LOG_FILES_LOCATION}/services/${spring.application.name}/${spring.application.name}.log
```

it also (not surprisingly) had no effect

how can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line.

```
log4j.appender.fileAppener=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
```